# ActiveAdmin nested DropDown Menu

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

The ActiveAdmin Docs mention the following Syntax to nest submenus:

```
# https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#customize-the-menu

ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  menu parent: ["Admin", "Blog"]
end
```

However I'm getting a TypeError:

```
Array isn't supported as a Menu ID
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [feature](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/5994) was only just added so you probably need to use master if you want it.